# Why constant double PI in math.cs assigned 20 characters after the point?

Tags: c#, pi

Why in *math.cs* the number Pi is assigned to the double type?
The constant PI 3.14159265358979323846 contains 20 characters after the point.
Type double can output only 14 of them. Why is this done?

```
// ==++==
// 
//   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// 
// ==--==
/*============================================================
**
** Class:  Math
**
**
** Purpose: Some floating-point math operations
**
** 
===========================================================*/
namespace System {

    //This class contains only static members and doesn't require serialization.
    using System;
    using System.Runtime;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
    using System.Runtime.Versioning;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

    public static class Math {

      private static double doubleRoundLimit = 1e16d;
      private const int maxRoundingDigits = 15;

      // This table is required for the Round function which can specify the number of digits to round to
      private static double[] roundPower10Double = new double[] { 
          1E0, 1E1, 1E2, 1E3, 1E4, 1E5, 1E6, 1E7, 1E8,
          1E9, 1E10, 1E11, 1E12, 1E13, 1E14, 1E15               };          

      public const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
      public const double E  = 2.7182818284590452354;
```

Comment: Because someone at Microsoft decided that is how it would be done. How do you expect anyone to answer this?

Comment: "double can output only 14 of them"? With `Math.PI.ToString("G20")` I get 16 digits after the comma (though not 20).

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic And what reading exactly of floating-point numbers answers the question?

Comment: @NightOwl888 That still does not explain why it was written this way if some of the decimal places are discarded. I find it a reasonable question, some code in the reference source isn't exactly what meets the eye, there might be some purposely built compiler magic that compiles it differently than what the source actually shows. Not saying this is the case.

Comment: Hmm, E has only 19 ... so if there was some of that "Compiler Magic" I'd expect both to have 20 places... or both 19 - whatever, but the same.

Comment: The Microsoft programmer could have spent more time finding the minimum number of digits that reproduces the exact same binary value.  And do so for every processor supported by .NET, the difference between the 80-bit internal storage on x86 and the 64-bit on x64 is notorious.  He decided to take a shortcut.

Comment: Maybe even "heritage" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/math-constants ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why in math.cs the number Pi is assigned to the double type?

Fundamentally, the constant has to be stored in some sort of data type.

double is one of the highest precision data types ([of the standard C# data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)).  The only other contender is decimal, and since the 'exact' value of PI is typically not relevant (let alone -cannot be represented as a number in non-infinite space), double is more appropriate.

> The constant PI 3.14159265358979323846 contains 20 characters after the point.
>   Type double can output only 14 of them. Why is this done?

It's always safer to have too many digits as opposed to too few digits.  Maybe on your system only 14 digits are displaced and/or stored, but other systems now or in the future may re-define double to be more more precise.  The code as it is written allows a certain degree of backward compatibility for the future.

As @René Vogt pointed out `Math.PI.ToString("G20")` returned 16 digits, for example.